# "If $a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x)=c$ has $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as its roots, then prove that...". What does "roots" refer to here?

Tags: trigonometry, roots

What does "roots" mean in the following problem? (I don't want a proof for this statement through this question.)

> If $a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x)=c$ has $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as its roots, then prove that
> $$\tan\alpha + \tan\beta = \dfrac{2b}{a+c}$$

I would like to clarify the meaning of "roots" in this question and try solving it myself later. Please don't post a proof for this statement.

So, I know what roots of a function mean. For a function $f$, $x$ is its root (or zero) if $f(x) = 0$. But, what we have here is an equation.

As I see it, it can mean two things

- When substituted in place of $x$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ would make the value of $c$ equal to $0$
- $a\cos(2x) + b\sin(2x) - c$ is the function and its value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is $0$. This would mean that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the solution of the given equation

I think that the latter is true. I know that this is a trivial question but I would like to get a clarification, nonetheless.

Thanks!

Comment: the latter is true

Comment: @HariRamakrishnanSudhakar Thanks!

Comment: $a,b,c$ are supposed to be *given* constants. You cannot assert that $c=0$.

Comment: @AkshatSharma Where did I assert that?

Comment: "When substituted in place of $x$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ would make the value of $c$ equal to $0$"

Comment: I didn't exactly 'assert' that $c=0$. I was basically saying that if $E$ and $F$ are expressions in terms of $x$ and $E = F$ is the equation that we're talking about, I had thought of two possibilities of the meaning of root(s) of this equation, first : zero of a function $f$ if $f(x) = E$ and two : zero of a function $f$ if $f(x) = E-F$. These two possibilities are expressed through the first and second bullets respectively. I do realize now that the first 'possibility' is obviously flawed because $E=F$ is equivalent to $F=E$ and so, the first possibility will cause inconsistencies

Comment: In your case, $F$ is a *given* constant, therefore $F=0$ would necessarily imply $E=0$.

Comment: $E$ isn't a constant, it's an expression in terms of $x$. You can think of it as a function in terms of $x$ too, though.

Comment: Oops, I meant $F$

Comment: Well, $F$ is an expression too...

Comment: And, I stated that $E = F$, so isn't it obvious that $F = 0 \implies E = 0$? I don't think I completely understand what you're trying to say, @AkshatSharma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111893/discussion-between-akshat-sharma-and-rajdeep-sindhu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually equations have roots and functions have zeroes. For example  the zeroes of the function $f: x \mapsto \sin(x)$ are $x_n=n \pi$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, while the roots of the equation $\sin(x)=0$ are $x_n=n\pi$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So, roots of an equation basically refer to the solutions of it, which can also be phrased as "If $E$ and $F$ are expressions in terms of a single variable, $x$ and $E = F$, then the roots of this equation are the roots of a function $f$ if $f(x) = E-F$", right?

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Did you want to write "...zeroes of a function $f$..."? Yes, that's the basic idea. As you can see, they are closely related.

Comment: Yes, zeroes...${}$

Answer (score 1):

The roots of the equation $$a\sin(2x) + b \cos(2x) = c $$
are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, it means that putting $x = \alpha, \beta,~$ the equation is satisfied. Namely $$ a\sin(2\alpha) + b \cos(2\alpha) = c \quad \text{and} \quad a \sin(2\beta) + b \cos(2\beta) = c $$
And as @Botond has told in his post, the notion of **roots** is for **equations** and the notion of **zeros** is for the **functions**.

Comment: Thank You! I got the answer from @Botond 's post itself but I feel that if someone isn't able to understand it completely from his post (because of the notations, maybe), he/she will be able to do it from yours. So, $+1$.

Comment: Thank You @RajdeepSindhu

Answer (score 1):

$$a \cos 2x+b \sin 2x=c \implies {a(1-t^2)+2bt}=c(1+t^2), t=\tan x$$
$$\tan x=\frac{b\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}}{(a+c)}\implies \alpha, \beta= \tan^{-1} \left (\frac{b\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2-c^2}}{(a+c)}\right)$$